# else if statement not responding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I have a project with a form that I validate with useForm from react-hook-form. Everything Is working fine, I have an onSubmit function which checks if the validation is correct and transfers the user to the next page. I have an if statement in that onSubmit function, which works fine, however, If I put an else if statement or an else statement in the same function, I get no response whatsoever, no errors, no bugs, just nothing and I'm wondering why that's happening. Here's the onSubmit function :

```
const [background, setBackground] = useState(false)
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if(data.name.length >= 2 && data.email.includes("something")){
        setState(true);
        setCorrect(true);   
    }else if(data.name.length < 2){
        setBackground(true)
    }
}
```

the If statement still works, but the else statement doesn't respond. Here's the shortened version of the form : "

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       {errors.name && 
       <Card classname="card1" text="Please enter a valid name" title="Name" />} 
       <div className='tickDiv'>
           <input style={{backgroundColor: background ? "red" : null}} value={values.name} 
            name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name*"
            {...register("name",{onChange:handleChange, required:true, minLength:2})} />
            {correct? <img className='tick' src={tick} /> : null}
        </div>
        <button type='submit' onClick={handleClick} className='next-button'><span>Next</span> 
        </button>
</form>
```

I just want to be able to change the background color of the input If the characters of value is less than 2 . Thank you in advance.

Comment: if data.name.length > 2 and does not include ('something') it wont get there, you need one more else at the end.

Comment: I think your onSubmit handler is wrong. change it to `onSubmit={onSubmit}` and see what I does

Comment: if(data.name.length >= 2 && data.email.includes("redberry.ge")){
        setState(true);
        setCorrect(true);   
    }else if(data.name.length < 2 && data.email.includes("something")){
        setBackground(true)
    } 
Like this or what do you mean by one more else statement?

Comment: no the onSubmit works fine, handleSubmit is a method from react-hook-form

Comment: @ceaiius maybe `else if (data.name.length > 2 && !data.email.includes("something"))` is what you're missing.

Comment: No it still doesn't work, Its not even console logging anything in that else if statement, I'm really confused haha

Comment: I it would be easier if u create an example on codesandbox or somewhere similar. That said, I think its better to set the background based on form.formState.errors returned from useForm hook.

Comment: I've tried that as well but I got a problem there too, is it possible to do this in a correct way? : {errors.name && <p>something<p> && setBackground(true)} something similar to this? when I use both the <p> tag and the setBackground in that method, it doesn't work, it works only If I have only either one of them, not both,  although this would be the simplest way to achieve what I want.

Comment: There is a suspicious `register("name",{ ..., minLength:2 })`, which obviously is using some validation library, like maybe [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register). I suppose that prevents the form to be submitted if the input has < 2 characters ?